# Is it possible to see Visits (not views) of a certain page in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am looking to find the number of visitors that see a certain subdomain on my website. I can find total views and unique views but not visitors. I thought you could do this fairly easily in the old GA but having a hard time finding it now.

Comment: it sounds like unique page views *is* what you want.. a regular page view counts each time a visitor hits the page during a session, regardless of how many times they hit it. A unique page view only counts once per session (visit) per visitor.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a custom report.

I'll share an easy example I created: https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=ReBbGcwqToSJeP_TyfrhsA

Look at report tab 1 to see visits and pageviews to your different pages. If you click the "Unique" report tab, you can see which hostname initiated the request and how many unique visitors was seen during that time period.